# Obtener elementos que no se repitan en un array javascript tipo string mediante filter de forma case unsensitive

Tags: javascript, array, string

Obtener elementos que no se repitan en un array javascript tipo string mediante filter de forma case unsensitive

```
  var x = ["a","a","A","C","c","D"];

var uniqs = x.filter(function(item, index, array) {
  return array.indexOf(item) === index;
})
console.log(uniqs); // resultado: **a,A,C,c,D**
```

Lo que espero es que el resultado de la función sea: **a,C,D**
Evitando que la función sea sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

He visto muchos otros ejemplos pero son utilizando número decimales en vez de cadenas. Me gustaría tener la solución utilizando esta función filter.

Se desea que devuelva el carácter en mayúscula o minúscula según la primera coincidencia que encuentre.

var x = ["a","a","A","C","c","D"];

Devuelve la primera a está en minúscula.
Devuelve la primera C está en mayúscula.
Devuelve la primera d está en mayúscula.

No me sirve un resultado que devuelva todo en mayúscula o todo en minúscula:

// resultado: **A,C,D**
// resultado: **a,c,d**

Answer (score 1):

En tu Iteración tienes que igualar las dos variables para determinar si ya existe, entonces debes convertir o a minúscula o mayúscula, pero solo en la validación y al insertar, será con el registro original.

Yo en este caso lo genero con un [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf),

```js
var x = ["a","a","A","C","c","D"];

uniqs = x.reduce((ant, curr)=> {
  if(ant.findIndex((a) => a.toLowerCase() == curr.toLowerCase()) == -1){
   ant.push(curr);
  }
  return ant;
}, [])
console.log(uniqs);
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema de usar `.filter` para este caso es que no podemos acceder a los valores intermedios que va tomando en cada iteración, por ello es que es mas conveniente utilizar `.reduce` de manera de poder usar el *acumulador*.

Para poder usar `.filter`, hay que forzar un poco las reglas y buenas prácicas de JavaScript:

```js
const x = ["a", "a", "A", "L", "l", "D"]; // <-- Cambié las C's por L's

let uniqs = [];

uniqs = x.filter(x=> 

  !(uniqs.includes(x.toLowerCase()) || uniqs.includes(x.toUpperCase())) && uniqs.push(x)

);

console.log(uniqs);
```

Si usaramos `.forEach` en lugar de `.filter` tambien funcionaría, la diferencia es que `.filter` está devolviendo el array filtrado y está reemplazando a `uniqs`, que en este caso particular va a tomar valores idénticos.

Esto se *puede* hacer pero no está 100% bien hacerlo. `uniqs` es una cosa hasta la anteúltima iteración y otra distinta cuando completa la última iteración.